# How to create a global confirmation message on delete in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every single `link_to :method => :delete` in my app includes a `:data => {:confirm => "Are you sure?"}`

In the spirit of DRY, is it possible to set this confirmation message once so it appears automatically throughout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to have a helper method

== application helper

```
def delete_link(object)
    raw (link_to 'Destroy', object, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' })
end
```

== view

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= job.title %></td>
    <td>
        <%= delete_link(job) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

and I checked it works :D

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery, basically adding some data if it contains `data-method="delete"`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-method="delete"]').data('confirm','Are you sure?');
    $('a[data-method="delete"]').attr('data-confirm','Are you sure?');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vuQU7/

Note that you must separately add the data and set the attribute - depending on the Rails UJS code, it will check one or the other (or both). So setting both will ensure it works.